# Boolean bit fields vs logical bit masking or bit shifting - C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a series of classes that are going to require many boolean fields, somewhere between 4-10. I'd like to not have to use a byte for each boolean. I've been looking into bit field structs, something like:

```
struct BooleanBitFields
    {
        bool b1:1;
        bool b2:1;
        bool b3:1;
        bool b4:1;
        bool b5:1;
        bool b6:1;
    };
```

But after doing some research I see a lot of people saying that this can cause inefficient memory access and not be worth the memory savings. I'm wondering what the best method for this situation is. Should I use bit fields, or use a char with bit masking (and's and or
s) to store 8bits? If the second solution is it better to bit shift or use logic?

If anyone could comment as to what method they would use and why it would really help me decide which route I should go down.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use whatever is more convenient for you unless you have hard data that this choice will impact the performance of your application in an observable manner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638015/how-slow-are-bit-fields-in-c<br/>
Bit fields will just do your masking for you.

Comment: Well that other post was right on topic, but it still seemed like there wasn't a direct answer to the question. :(

Comment: I am curious: What type of software do you build and why do you think that wasting approx. 8 bytes really makes a difference?

Comment: It's going to be server code for a game in which these classes define what makes a user in the game. Thus there will potentially be thousands of allocations of this class in existence at one time and it seems like it should be designed efficiently. Although even in the worst case with bools being allocated to 64bit chunks, assuming each user wastes 8bools and 10,000 users it comes out to ~5MB of wasted memory on a server with at least 8 gigs of RAM. Probably isn't even an issue.

Comment: @user1229962 exactly that's what I thought when I read your question. Imo, stuff like this is premature optimization which often leads to unclear/difficult to understand code code and should be avoided / tweaked later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the large address spaces on desktop boxes, an array of 32/64-bit booleans may seem wasteful, and indeed it is, but most developers don't care, (me included).  On RAM-restricted embedded controllers, or when accessing hardware in drivers, then sure, use bitfields, otherwise..

One other issue, apart from R/W ease/speed, is that a 32- or 64-bit boolean is thread-safer than one bit in the middle that has to be manipulated by multiple logical operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use an int bit array (leaves you lots of space to expand, and there is no advantage to a single char) and test with mask constants:

```
#define BOOL_A 1
#define BOOL_B 1 << 1
#define BOOL_C 1 << 2
#define BOOL_D 1 << 3

/* Alternately: use const ints for encapsulation */    

// declare and set
int bitray = 0 | BOOL_B | BOOL_D;

// test
if (bitray & BOOL_B) cout << "Set!\n";
```

Comment: Thanks goldilocks. Do you have any reasons for choosing this method over bit fields?

Comment: That **is** a bit field, it just isn't declared as a struct with named members.  Instead, named constants are used.  This seems simpler and tidier to me (and is more normative).  The only disadvantage is you have to be careful with the names, as they are in global space.  Giving them all the same prefix is a conventional solution, since MYFIELD_VALUEA is akin to MyField::ValueA.  You could use const ints here too I guess.

Comment: Using const ints instead of defines permits better encapsulation but may be a (very weeny) performance hit.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever It's not a bit field -- it's a bit *flag*. The word "field", used alone, means the same thing as you call a "member". It has nothing to do with bit flags/masks. A bit field is *specifically* used within a struct.

Comment: @CraigBarnes Point taken.

Answer (score 1):

Bit fields are only a recommendation for the compiler. The compiler is free to implement them as it likes. On embedded systems there are compilers that guarantee 1 bit-to-bit mapping. Other compilers don't.

I would go with a regular struct, like yours but no bit fields. Make them unsigned chars - the shortest data type. The struct will make it easier to access them while editing, if your IDE supports auto completion.

Comment: Also phrased as "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field." -- ISO C11 §6.7.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I want to write an answer to make sure once again and formalize the thought: "What does the transition from working with bytes to working with bits entail?" And also because the answer "I don't care" seems to me to be unreasonable.

## Exploring char vs bitfield

Agree, It's very tempting. Especially when it's supposed to be used like this:

```c
#define FLAG_1 1
#define FLAG_2 (1 << 1)
#define FLAG_3 (1 << 2)
#define FLAG_4 (1 << 3)

struct S1 {
    char flag_1: 1;
    char flag_2: 1;
    char flag_3: 1;
    char flag_4: 1;
}; //sizeof == 1

void MyFunction(struct S1 *obj, char flags) {
    obj->flag_1 = flags & FLAG_1;
    obj->flag_2 = flags & FLAG_2;
    obj->flag_3 = flags & FLAG_3;
    obj->flag_4 = flags & FLAG_4;
    // we desire it to be as *obj = flags;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct S1 obj;
    MyFunction(&obj, FLAG_1 | FLAG_2 | FLAG_3 | FLAG_4);
    
    return 0;
}
```

But let's cover all aspects of such optimization. Let's decompose the operation into simpler C-commands, roughly corresponding to the assembler commands:

1. Initialization of all flags.

```c
    char flags = FLAG_1 | FLAG_3;
    //obj->flag_1 = flags & FLAG_1;
    //obj->flag_2 = flags & FLAG_2;
    //obj->flag_3 = flags & FLAG_3;
    //obj->flag_4 = flags & FLAG_4;
    *obj = flags;
```

2. Writing one flag as a constant

```c
    //obj.flag_3 = 1;
    char a = *obj;
    a &= ~FLAG_3;
    a |= FLAG_3;
    *obj = a;
```

3. Write a single flag using a variable

```c
    char b = 3;
    //obj.flag_3 = b;
    char a = *obj;
    a &= ~FLAG_3;
    
    char c = b;
    c <<= 3;
    c &= ~FLAG_3; //Fixing b > 1
    
    a |= c;
    *obj = a;
```

4. Reading one flag into variable

```c
    //char f = obj.flag_3;
    char f = *obj;
    f >>= 3;
    f &= 0x01;
```

5. Write one flag to another

```c
  //obj.flag_2 = obj.flag_4;
  char a = *obj;
  char b = a;
  a &= FLAG_4;
  a <<= 2; //Shift to FLAG_2 position
  b |= a;
  *obj = b;
```

### Resume

| Command | Cost, bitfield | Cost, variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. Init | 1 | 4 or less |
| 2. `obj.flag_3 = 1;` | 3 | 1 |
| 3. `obj.flag_3 = b;` | 7 | 1 or 3 * |
| 4. `char f = obj.flag_3;` | 2 | 1 |
| 5. `obj.flag_2 = obj.flag_4;` | 6 | 1 |

*- if we guarantee flag be no more than 1

All operations except initialization take many lines of code. It looks like it would be better for us to leave bit fields alone after initialization)))). However, this is usually what happens to flags all the time. They change their state without warning and randomly.

> **We are essentially trying to make the rare value initialization operation cheaper by sacrificing frequent value change operations.**

There are systems in which bitwise comparison operations, bit **set** and **reset**, bit **copying** and even bit **swapping**, bit **branching**, take one cycle. There are even systems in which **mutex locking operations** are implemented by a single assembler instruction (in such systems, bit fields may not be located on the entire memory area, for example, PIC microcontrollers). in any way it's not a common memory area.

Perhaps in such systems, the bool type could point to a component of the bitfield.

If your desire to save on insignificant bits of a byte has not yet disappeared, try to think about implementing **addressability**, **atomicity** of operations, **arithmetic** with bytes, and the resulting overhead for **calls**, **data** memory, **code** memory, **stack** if algorithms are placed in functions.

## Reflections on the choice of `bool` or `char`

If your target platform decodes the `bool` type as 2 bytes or 4 or more. That most likely operations with bits on it will not be optimized. Rather, it is a platform for high-volume computing. This means that bit operations are not so in demand on it, in addition, operations with bytes and words are not so in demand on it.

In the same way that operations on bits hurt performance, operations on a single byte can also greatly increase the number of cycles to access a variable.

No system can be equally optimal for everything at once. Instead of obsessing over memory savings in systems that are clearly built with a lot of memory surplus, pay attention to the strengths of those systems.

## Conclusion

**Use `char` or `bool` if:**

1. You need to store the mutable state or behavior of the algorithm (and change and return flags individually).
2. Your flag does not accurately describe the system and could evolve into a number.
3. You need to be able to access the flag by address.
4. If your code claims to be platform independent and there is no guarantee that bit operations will be optimized on the target platform.

**Use bitfields if:**

1. You need to store a huge number of flags without having to constantly read and rewrite them.
2. You have unusually tight memory requirements, or memory is low.
3. In other deeply justified cases, with calculations and confirming experiments.

**Perhaps a short rule might be:**

> **Independent flags are stored in a `bool`.**

**P.S.:** If you've read this far and still want to save 7 bits out of 8, then consider why there is no desire to use 7 bit bit fields for variables that take a value up to 100 maximum.

## References

[Raymond Chen: The cost-benefit analysis of bitfields for a collection of booleans](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081126-00/?p=20073)